# Get config data in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am aware that this:

```
$this->container->getParameter('param_name')
```

...will get the parameter name from the main config file in /app/config/.

But how do I get config data from the config file in the bundle's config file and in a method inside an event listener class. The code runs on every request (the config file is in the bundle which holds the event listener class).

I am writing a bundle which based on the user agent gives permissions to different devices. So I will detect the device into a group, e.g. "IPHONE", "IPAD", "ANDROID_4+", "ANDROID_<4" etc. and then my config file would look something like this:

```
parameters:
    allow_feature_1: IPHONE, IPAD, ANDROID_4+
    allow_feature_2: IPHONE, IPAD, ANDROID_<4, ANDROID_4+
```

I just need to get those config values into my class.

I have all the event listener code done.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should store your parameters in separate file parameters.yml and import this file in config.yml. For getting access for parameters from parameters.yml in an event listener you should inject this parameters http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/service_container.html#service-parameters (for sf2.1).